# How to pass a rotated image within an ImageView to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, rotation, imageview

In my app, I'm rotating an image on a button click. Now when I pass the image to another activity, I don't want to loose the image's rotation angle.

This is how I rotate the image.

In onclick of button 'rotate'

```
btn_rotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rotateImage(true);
        }

    });

public void rotateImage(boolean rotate) {
    RotateAnimation animation = null;
    if (rotate) {
        animation = new RotateAnimation(rotation, rotation + 90,
        picview.getWidth() / 2, picview.getHeight() / 2);
        rotation += 90;
        rotation %= 360;
    } else {
        animation = new RotateAnimation(0, rotation,
        picview.getWidth() / 2, picview.getHeight() / 2);

    }
    animation.setDuration(0);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());        
    picview.startAnimation(animation);

}
```

I pass the rotation angle as:

```
send_image.putExtra("rotation_angle", rotation);
```

But in the receiving activity how do I apply the rotation_angle on the Image? Can someone please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: animarions are used for animating things, what you are doing with them is overuse

Answer (score 0):

As a best practices do not pass the bitmap from the intent as it is heavy object.
Instead you can have few options like

```
 1. In your application class with get and set bitmap
 2. Save rotated bitmap into Sdcard in one activity and retrieve that in other activity
```

Hope it helps